# HBase Failover situation

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I'm kind of new to HBase and I'm trying to find the solution for HBase failover situation. So here is the whole picture of what is happening. We have 3 zookeeper nodes, 2 Hbase master nodes and some region servers. When hbase failovers to from 1 master to another we have recycle our service in order to get our services to hit hbase otherwise we get ConnectionRefused exception. I'm not sure what we are doing wrong or if we are missing any configuration or something. the same thing happens when we use the hbase shell and if there is a master failover happens then it starts throwing the same error. Can anyone please help me in knowing why this is happening? FYI We are using hbase 0.94.2

The error we see is as follows

```
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
$Proxy81.getHTableDescriptors(Unknown Source)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHTableDescriptor(HConnectionManager.java:1834)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getTableDescriptor(HTable.java:440)

root cause
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:567)
org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:207)
org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:525)
org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:489)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupConnection(HBaseClient.java:416)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient$Connection.setupIOstreams(HBaseClient.java:462)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.getConnection(HBaseClient.java:1150)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.HBaseClient.call(HBaseClient.java:1000)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.WritableRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(WritableRpcEngine.java:150)
$Proxy81.getHTableDescriptors(Unknown Source)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HConnectionManager$HConnectionImplementation.getHTableDescriptor(HConnectionManager.java:1834)
org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.HTable.getTableDescriptor(HTable.java:440)
```

Here is the config. I have replace the zookeeper quorum with zk

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>dfs.client.read.shortcircuit</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>my.property</name>
    <value>value</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.handler.count</name>
    <value>30</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.hregion.max.filesize</name>
    <value>10737418240</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.pause</name>
    <value>30000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs-path</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>zk1,zk2,zk3</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.keyvalue.maxsize</name>
    <value>209715200</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.codecs</name>
    <value>snappy,lzo,gz</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.hstore.blockingStoreFiles</name>
    <value>25</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.scanner.caching</name>
    <value>100</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.replication</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.snapshot.enabled</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.hregion.majorcompaction</name>
    <value>0</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.checksum.verify</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.bulkload.staging.dir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hbase-staging</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.coprocessor.region.classes</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.security.access.SecureBulkLoadEndpoint</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.regionserver.region.split.policy</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.ConstantSizeRegionSplitPolicy</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.client.retries.number</name>
    <value>3</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>zookeeper.recovery.retry</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could you add the error and configuration files?

Comment: error added. Which configuration are you looking for the client or the hbase master?

Comment: the conf/hbase-site.xml

Comment: added the hbase-site.xml